# Edit XSL file using Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I have the following XSL file: http://pastebin.com/H8CYPGUF

I want to edit the following part:

```
<xsl:template name="testOptions">
<table class="details" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="95%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <th align="left">userType</th>
        <th align="left">numberOfThreads</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>customer</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>admin</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr size="1" />
```

To something like:

```
<xsl:template name="testOptions">
<table class="details" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="95%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <th align="left">userType</th>
        <th align="left">numberOfThreads</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>customer</td>
        <td>HERE GOES THE NEW VALUE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>admin</td>
        <td>HERE GOES THE NEW VALUE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr size="1" />
```

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: In how far is Python involved? In a XSLT stylesheet, I would just add a new template with the following XPath: `table/tr/td[2]` and fill in something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using lxml to parse and traverse the document tree. lxml treats a nodes children as a list, which makes the conditional updates to sibling nodes fairly simple. Also lxml outputs the xsl namespaces by default.

```
import io
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse(io.FileIO('input.xsl'))

for tr in doc.findall(".//tr"):
    if tr[0].tag == 'td':
        if tr[0].text == 'customer' :
            if tr[1].tag == 'td' :
                 tr[1].text = 'new value 1'
        elif tr[0].text == 'admin' :
            if tr[1].tag == 'td' :
                tr[1].text = 'new value 2'

print (etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print = True))
```

Actually, you could even generalize this a bit using a function to replace the text value of any node whose preceding-sibling matches a value:

```
def mod(match,value) :
    for n in doc.xpath(".//*[preceding-sibling::*/text()='%s']" % match):
        n.text = value

mod('customer', 'new customer value')
mod('admin', 'new admin value')
```

Comment: This is great. I was struggling to find a simple solution but this is perfect. Thanks.